# Keyboard shortcut to prevent login items from loading but still allow extensions

Tags: keyboard, startup

I know that if I boot my Mac while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then it does "safe mode" which causes it to boot without either login items or extensions. I often want to boot the computer and not load login items but still load the extensions!

Any keyboard shortcut whiz know what keys would have that effect at boot?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Disable automatic login in system preferences - users and groups - login options.

Reboot

At the login window type your password and then immediately hold down shift.

This will disable login items on a per login basis.

With proper timing this can be accomplished even with automatic login enabled. You must hold shift as soon as the spinning gear stops.

If you are talking about Lion Resume, that's another story.

Comment: since you're talking about the same "shift" key -- can you confirm, your method allows the "extensions" but locks out the "login items"?   (seems that way, but wanted to confirm. Thanks!!)

Comment: Actually, of course, I went and tried to confirm it myself (it was silly of me to ask you to confirm it.)   When I did as you said, and hit shift RIGHT after I typed my password+enter, and waited, it seems good.  Didn't load the startup items. But I realize that I can't even remember how to confirm if "extensions" were not loaded. Now that I'm actually thinking of it, I haven't seen "extensions" for a long time, before OS X in fact!  Do extensions still EXIST?  Perhaps my whole question above is silly since my computer is OS X Lion and extensions are a thing of the past?

Answer (score 0):

## For Mountain Lion

If the startup volume is **not** encrypted with Core Storage (typically FileVault 2):

- [the answer given by aaa](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53248/8546) should be good.

If the startup volume is encrypted with Core Storage:

1. hear the startup chime
2. at EfiLoginUI: type, but do not enter, a passphrase for the disk or for a user
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> and do not release <kbd>Shift</kbd> until loginwindow presents a user, or list of users
4. for a selected user: type, but do not enter, the password
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> and do not release <kbd>Shift</kbd> until after login is complete.